# Prevent redirection using url

Tags: java, struts2

I have an application written in Java Struts 2. We detected an open redirect vulnerability.

Open redirect occurs when a web page is being redirected to another URL in another domain via a user-controlled input.

For example: 
when we try URL like `myapp.abc.com/test.action?redirect:google.com/?`, it redirects to `google.com`.

I need to prevent this for security concerns. It should not redirect to any other domain except our domain. How do I prevent this type of attack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect parameter is blocked by the [S2-016](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/S2-016).

If you still use it then you should parse parameters manually via the request.

Probably you need to learn [how Struts2 handles request parameters from the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32147194/573032).

Since the special parameters are handled by the `ActionMapper`. And default implementation is used to remove vulnerable parameters then you need to write a custom action mapper.

To use custom action mapper with struts you need to configure it via

```
constant name="struts.mapper.class" value="restaurants" />
```