# Create custom Action Mapping in Struts 2

Tags: struts2

How to create a Custom Action Mapping in Struts 2?
Anyone give me a example or refer something about this..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define "custom action mapping".

Comment: You have probably start with https://stackoverflow.com/a/49235917/573032

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below tag in struts.xml file
For Example:

```
<action name="Login" class="com.LoginAction" method="userLoginAction">
  <result name="success">/Menu.jsp</result>
  <result name="input">/Login.jsp</result>
</action>
```